# Bash script: Eqw status

Tags: bash

I've been trying to run this code in a server but always send an 'Eqw' status.
I want to process a file that contains three columns, one with a path, and the others are information about that file.
Can anyone please help me to figure out what's wrong in my code?

```
#!/bin/bash
source $HOME/.bashrc
source /share/apps/Profiles/share-profile.sh
module load compilers/python-2.7.15

MANIFEST=path with the file with three columns
TRIM=trimming program that does work properly

#Run pyadapter_trim.py to trim adapter sequences
COUNTER=0;
#for each file in the input manifest, run tirimming program
while read LINE
do
    READ=`echo "$LINE" | awk -F"\t" '{print $1}'`
    SAMPLE=`echo "$LINE"  | awk -F"\t" '{print $2}'`
    GENOME=`echo "$LINE"  | awk -F"\t" '{print $3}'`
    WDIR=`(dirname $READ1)`
    cd $WDIR
    QCDIR=$WDIR"/ats"
    mkdir -p $QCDIR
    echo -e "Processing sample ${SAMPLE}"
    echo -e "${READ1}..."
    python $TRIM -a $READ
    echo ""
    COUNTER=`expr $COUNTER + 1`

done < "$MANIFEST"
echo "$COUNTER Files Processed"
```

Comment: `while IFS=$'\t' read READ SAMPLE GENOME _` would be much more efficient than the `awk` mess, btw. And as another aside, it's best to avoid `echo -e` unless you have a specific and compelling reason to use it. (As another, `expr` is an artifact of the 1970s and should never be used in new code; `COUNTER=$(( COUNTER + 1 ))` is far faster to run, and compatible with all shells that comply with the 1992 POSIX.2 standard).

Comment: Beyond that -- all-caps variable names are in a reserved namespace (used for variables meaningful to the shell and system itself), and best avoided. And there area number of bugs relating to missing quoting that http://shellcheck.net/ will point out.

Comment: ...beyond that, though -- `Eqw` doesn't really mean anything to me. Can you generate a [mcve] others can use to reproduce your problem themselves, without needing to also have your input files, or your `pyadapter_trim` script, or such?

Comment: Another thing you can use to help build a more answerable question is to trace your script's operation, as with `bash -x yourscript` -- if you track each command logged from that trace, you can figure out the first time a specific command behaves a way you don't expect it to, and thus narrow the question to focus on what *specifically* is wrong.

Comment: Since you `cd $WDIR`, you don't need to use the `$WDIR` prefix when creating the `ats` subdirectory, you can just do `mkdir ats`.

Comment: I also don't know what you mean by "Eqw status". It's not common terminology, I guess it's something specific to your python script.